# method sort not sorting last nested array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, methods

somehow arr[i].sort() not sorting last nested array and i getting bad result.
try`ed FOR and WHILE, different operators, nothing helped. what i`m doing wrong?
it have return biggest numbers in array.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i != arr.length) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].sort().pop();
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}

largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 8, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 817, 1]
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in sort defaults - it sorts the array as strings - so "8..." > "1..."

Try following:

```
function cmp(a,b){
  return a-b;
}

function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i != arr.length) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].sort(cmp).pop();
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}

largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 8, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 817, 1]
]);
```

Output:  `[ 8, 27, 39, 1001 ]`

Answer (score 2):

By default `sort()` orders the elements as strings, not numbers, and `"1001" < "817"`. If you want a numeric sort you need to provide a comparison function that performs numeric ordering.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i != arr.length) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    }).pop();
    i++;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 8, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 817, 1]
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cause of the problem you are seeing (which @Barmar answered), but you can use `Array.map` with `Math.max.apply` to get the max number of each list:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
   return arr.map(function(list) {
      return Math.max.apply(null, list);
   });
}

console.log(largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 8, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 817, 1]
]));
```

Or a bit more concise with ES6:

```
const largestOfFour = arr => arr.map(list => Math.max(...list))
```